# Poll interval option on Apollo client useQuery hook not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have a simple forum-like app using apollo server and client(react) and I am trying to periodically update the posts on the main page using the pollInterval option on the useQuery hook. It doesn't seem to actually do anything, when I make a new post the page isn't updated.

Here is my query to get all the posts in the DB,

```
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(QUERY_POSTS, {
    pollInterval: 1000,
  });
```

and I am mapping through the data here

```
{loading && <div>loading....</div>}

        {data?.posts.map((post) => (
          <Card className="mb-5 w-50 " key={post._id}>
            {post.imgUrl && <Card.Img variant="top" src={post.imgUrl} />}

            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Text>{post.postText}</Card.Text>
              <Button
                variant="warning"
                type="button"
                onClick={(e) => handlePostLike(post._id, e)}
              >
                {post.likeCount} <BsFillEmojiSunglassesFill />
              </Button>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        ))}
```

Not sure if I should be using a subscription or if I am just using the polling feature incorrectly.

Comment: It looks like this is a reported bug: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9819

Comment: @cdnicoll Yep, just tried out manually starting the poll using startPolling like someone said in that gh issue. Works now, thanks!

Comment: Didn't that kept the polling all the time?